# Main Activity won't launch on Kotlin project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, launch

I have two activities, QuizQuestions, and MainActivity2. When I set up QuizQuestions in the Manifest intent filter the app opens and launches fine. However when I set up my app to open with MainActivity2 it fails to initialize at all. I have looked at the files side by side and I cannot find what the difference in them is to see why one would launch and the other wont.

I am brand new to Kotlin so I am sure it is something very obvious that I am missing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Here is my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.crazywkids.officequiz">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.OfficeQuiz">

    <activity
        android:name=".QuizQuestions"
        android:exported="true"
        />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is MainActivity2

```
    package com.crazywkids.officequiz

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        val beginBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.beginBtn)

        beginBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, QuizQuestions::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }


    }
}
```

Here is QuizQuestions

```
    package com.crazywkids.officequiz

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class QuizQuestions : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_questions)

        val question=Constants.getQuestions()
        Log.i("Question Size", "${question.size}")
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you got in the logcat?

Comment: The log will have a stack trace that tells you which line of code caused the crash and why. I’m guessing that the layout you set in MainActivity2 doesn’t have a button with ID `”beginBtn”`.

Comment: Thank you. I looked at the logcat (which I didn't think to look at before) and found an InflateException on my image. I simply had to move my image to the drawable folder on the project level and it loaded fine. Thank you both for your help!